# Cocoa application plugins

Tags: cocoa, macos, plugins, monomac

I'm wondering if there is some kind of best practice on how to make your application able to take third party developer's own plugins and how to get started on that. I'd love to have a view in my settings where the user can add or remove the plugins. To me this is completely new so I'm thankful for any hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Code Loading Programming Topics](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/Plugins.html) section on plug-in archietecture.

> This section describes how to architect an application for extensibility through plug-ins. If you want to make your application modular, customizable, and easily extensible, you should read this section to learn about the different ways to build a plug-in architecture.